# How to work on a "subset" of a DataTable filtered via LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, system.data.datatable

Let's say I have a table with a Color column. Color can have various values. I have a C# method that can handle items of a given column at a time. Thus, I would like to :

```
foreach(colorname in mytable.getDistinctColornames)
   monocolorMethod(mytable.getSubTableOnlyContainingRowsWithColor(colorname))
```

How would I do that elegantly ... ?

At all prices, I would avoid copying the data back & forth. I would like kind of a view on the datatable. A view that would only "show" the rows of a given columns, and a "writable" view (i.e. when I write to the filtered subset, the original table is written to)

**EDIT :**

Let's say I have a 'Car' Table, and I would like to replace 'Sedan' by 'Truck' in column 'Type' for all cars with 'Color=Red'.

How would I do given the following code ?

```
DataTable cars (...); // the data

DataView dv = cars.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "Color='Red'";
```

< Here I would like to loop on the DataView>. The following code does not work :

```
foreach (row in dv.AsEnumerable)
{
  if(row["Type"] == "Sedan")
    row["Type"] = "Truck";
}
```

EDIT 2 :

Found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.dataview.allowedit.aspx which suggests

```
view.AllowEdit = true;
view[0].BeginEdit();
view[0]["FirstName"] = "Mary";
view[0]["LastName"] = "Jones";
view[0].EndEdit();
```

Comment: Can you show us some code on what you have already tried or what you're working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `DataView` class? It looks like exactly what you want to achieve without using LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdcwwhez

**An example of usage:**

Let say there is a `DataTable` object named `_dt` with 4 rows in it:

```
_dt = new DataTable("") {Columns = {new DataColumn("ID"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Order")}};
_dt.Rows.Add(1, "one", 1);
_dt.Rows.Add(2, "two", 3);
_dt.Rows.Add(3, "three", 2);
_dt.Rows.Add(4, "four", 5);
```

You can easily create DataView which doesn't filter data but perform sorting operation on it:

```
_dv = new DataView(_dt, "", "Order, Name", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

You can also add new rows into the `DataView` and because it is set on corresponding `DataTable` that new row will be added directly to `_dt` object. The sorting order will be updated as well, and new row won't be the last one within the `DataView` (because sort is done on Order and Name columns)

```
var newRow = _dv.AddNew();
newRow["ID"] = 5;
newRow["Name"] = "five";
newRow["Order"] = 4;
newRow.EndEdit();
```

After that code there will be 5 rows in `_dt`. Editing rows is also quite simple:

```
var editedRow = _dv[0];
editedRow.BeginEdit();
editedRow["Name"] = "Test";
editedRow.EndEdit();
```

You can also use [`DataView.Find()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbc8dtsx) or [`DataView.FindRows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwt6tf2t) methods to find a row within the `DataView`.

Comment: could you please give an example ? Let's say I'd want my view to be the table itself, but sorted by a first column, then a second one (equivalent to OrderBy(A).ThenBy(B)). Will the writes to the DataView be automatically performed on the original table ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope that example will help you with your problem.

Comment: Just wondering : how do you actually browse the DataView to edit the values of some of its rows (and thus, of the original DataTable)

Comment: You don't have to modify the data through the `DataView`. You can easily modify it by `DataTable`, and the view would be updated as well.

Comment: Let's say that the algorithm I use needs to browse the *Datatable* in a given order (e.g. with increasing IDs). I thought I could write to the *DataView*, sorted by ID. Does that make sense ?

Comment: then my problem is precisely to know how to write to _dv (as opposed to _dt)

Comment: Example for adding new rows is already in my answer. I also updated it with an edit example.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this:

[Querying DataSets – Introduction to LINQ to DataSet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/01/26/querying-datasets-introduction-to-linq-to-dataset.aspx)